# Scheme: given a list of lists and a permutation, permute

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, permutation

I am practicing for my programming paradigms exam and working through problem sets I come to this problem. This is the first problem after reversing and joining lists recursively, so I suppose there is an elegant recursive solution.

I am given a list of lists and a permutation. I should permute every list including a list of lists with that specified permutation.

I am given an example:

```
->(permute '((1 2 3) (a b c) (5 6 7)) '(1 3 2))
->((1 3 2) (5 7 6) (a c b))
```

I have no idea even how to start. I need to formulate the problem in recursive interpretation to be able to solve it, but I can not figure out how.

Comment: My biggest trouble was actually not knowing list-ref function. And it did not occur to me that it was a simple function, with a simple implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another option, using higher-order functions. This is the idiomatic way to think about a solution in a functional language - we split the problem in sub-problems, solve each one using existing procedures and finally we compose the answer:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (null? x))
       (not (pair? x))))

(define (perm lst order)
  (foldr (lambda (idx acc)
           (cons (list-ref lst (sub1 idx)) acc))
         '()
         order))

(define (permute lst order)
  (if (atom? lst)
      lst
      (perm (map (lambda (x) (permute x order)) lst)
            order)))
```

We start by defining `atom?`, a generic predicate and `perm`, a helper that will reorder any given list according to the ordering specified in one of its parameters. It uses `foldr` to build the output list and `list-ref` to access elements in a list, given its 0-based indexes (that's why we subtract one from each index).

The main `permute` function takes care of (recursively)  mapping `perm` on each element of an arbitrarily nested input list, so we can obtain the desired result:

```
(permute '((1 2 3) (a b c) (5 6 7)) '(1 3 2))
=> '((1 3 2) (5 7 6) (a c b))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful to me. I needed to shift my view of the problem from recursion to higher order functions, it is much clearer and simpler this way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's see how we can break this problem down. We are given a list of lists, and a list of numbers, and we want to order each list according to the order specified by the list of numbers:

```
=>(permute '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)) '(3 2 1))
'((3 2 1) (6 5 4))
```

We can see that each list in the list of lists can be handled separately, their solutions are unrelated to each other. So we can have a helper `permute1` that handles the case of one list, then use `map` to apply this function to each of the lists (with the same ordering each time):

```
(define (permute lists ordering)
  (map (lambda (xs) (permute1 xs ordering))
       lists))

(define (permute1 items ordering)
  ...)
```

Now, to calculate `(permute1 '(4 5 6) '(3 2 1))`, what we mean is:

1. The first item of the new list will be the `3`rd item of `items`, because the first number in `ordering` is `3`.
2. The rest of the items of the new list will be determined by using the rest of the numbers in the ordering.
3. If the ordering is the empty list, return the empty list.

This forms the base case (3), the recursive case (1), and the steps to recur deeper (2). So a sketch of our solution would look like:

```
(define (permute1 items ordering)
  (if (empty? ordering)
      '()
      (let ([next-item ???])
        (??? next-item
             (permute1 items (rest ordering))))))
```

Where the `???`s represent getting the item based on the first number in `ordering` and combining this item with the remainder of the calculation, respectively.

Comment: first ??? is actually list-ref that takes car ordering as argument, second ??? is cons , and rest ordering is cdr ordering . . .  Then actual code looks like this :                                 (define (permute1 items ordering)    
 (if (empty? ordering)    
    '()    
     (let ((next-item (list-ref items (- (car ordering) 1))))    
       (cons next-item    
             (permute1 items (cdr ordering))))))      Thank you very much!

Comment: Right! Although `rest` is actually a bona fide function in the Racket dialect of scheme, where you can use `first` and `rest` instead of `car` and `cdr`. I don't know what Scheme you're implementing this in though.

Comment: MZScheme/PrettyBig, R5RS included

Answer (score 0):

> I am given an example:
>
> ```
> (permute ('(1 2 3) '(a b c) '(5 6 7)) '(1 3 2))
> ((1 3 2) (5 7 6) (a c b))
> ```

The syntax you've given isn't correct, and will cause an error, but it's fairly clear what you mean.  You want that

```
(permute '((1 2 3) (a b c) (5 6 7)) '(1 3 2))
;=> ((1 3 2) (5 7 6) (a c b))
```

Now, it's not clear how you're indicating the permutation.  Is **'(1 3 2)** a permutation because it has some (1-based) indices, and indicates the way to rearrange elements, or is it because it is actually a permutation of the elements of the first list of the first list?  E.g., would

```
(permute '((x y z) (a b c) (5 6 7)) '(1 3 2))
;=> ((x z y) (5 7 6) (a c b))
```

work too?  I'm going to assume that it would, because it will make the problem much easier.

> I have no idea even how to start. I need to formulate the problem in
>   recursive interpretation to be able to solve it, but I can not figure
>   out how.

You need to write a function that can take a list of indices, and that returns a function that will perform the permutation.  E.g,.

```
(define (make-permutation indices)
  …)
```

such that

```
((make-permutation '(3 1 2)) '(a b c))
;=> (c a b)
```

One you have that, it sounds like your **permute** function is pretty simple:

```
(define (permute lists indices)
  (let ((p (make-permutation indices)))
    (p (map p lists))))
```

That would handle the case you've given in your example, since **(map p lists)** will return **((1 3 2) (a b c) (5 7 6))**, and then calling **p** with that will return **((1 3 2) (5 7 6) (a c b))**.  If you need to be able to handle more deeply nested lists, you'll need to implement a recursive mapping function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take, which seems to be shorter than the previous examples:

```
(define (permute lst ord)
  (define ord-1 (map sub1 ord)) ; change from 1-based to 0-based indexes
  (define (perm elts)           ; recursive sub-procedure
    (if (list? elts)
        (map perm (map (curry list-ref elts) ord-1)) ; list -> recurse
        elts))                                       ; else return unchanged
  (perm lst))                   ; initial call
```

testing

```
> (permute '((1 2 3) (a b c) (5 6 7)) '(1 3 2))
'((1 3 2) (5 7 6) (a c b))
> (permute '((1 (i permute did) 3) (a b (scheme cool is)) (5 6 7)) '(1 3 2))
'((1 3 (i did permute)) (5 7 6) (a (scheme is cool) b))
```